# Android - element to use for free text area

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm planning an android app and my first doubt came on what element should I use to represent a free text area.
I want to develop a quick note type of app and I want to know which kind of element is better to represent an area where the user can freely write that will automatically make newlines and with support for scroll.

So, can anyone help me?

Thx in advance,
CR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 3 attributes are important: singleLine, inputType, lines. Also, you may need a scrollbar, the code below shows how to make one:

```
<EditText
android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
android:lines="8"
android:minLines="6" 
android:gravity="top|left" 
android:maxLines="10" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple EditText should be sufficient with some tweaking. Something like this:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="100dip"
    android:inputType="textLongMessage" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it as soon as I can.

Comment: Try also android:inputType="textMultiLine"

Answer (score 1):

use edit text with `android:singleLine="false"`